# Same Origin Policy is browser restriction, is it secure on server-side?

Tags: cors, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I've researched and known that Same Origin Policy (SOP) is the client-based policy handled by the browser. The server is responsible for sending back browser the list allow-origin and browser check it with the current origin then decide to read the response or not. Maybe some case browser will send a prelight request to check. But all of the is the work of browser (client). Server still receive the request from the different domain and execute it then send the response. And SOP is not available for a request come from another server (server to server request), request come from POSTMAN... So I think server is still insecure with SOP.

Can anyone explain more about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly true that the existence of the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) doesn't mean that the server is secure from attack. The SOP is a very specific protection that operates in the specific context of a browser. Even with the SOP and proper CORS use, you still need [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection, for example. And you're still vulnerable to server bugs that can be exploited by an attacker. And so on.

The SOP serves to prevent code running in the browser from reading data from a different domain. That's all.